# Python - Counting values in a column based on the values in other columns for a specific user

Tags: python-3.x

I have already searched my problem on stackoverflow, but didn't find any proper answer.

I have a dataframe.
I'm trying to count the number of each Action for a Type for each User.

```
User     Type      Action
User1    Game      Start
User1    Game      End
User2    Movie     Start
User2    Movie     Start
User2    Movie     End
User3    Movie     Start
User3    Movie     End
User4    Game      Start
User4    Movie     Start
User1    Movie     Start
User1    Movie     End
```

I am interested to have another df that looks like this:

```
User    Game_start Movie_start Game_end Movie_end
User1   1          1           1        1
User2   0          2           0        1
User3   0          1           0        1
User4   1          1           0        0
```

Can anybody help me?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using mostly `pandas` methods

You could create a proxy column `Event` and then your problem is just a `groupby().count()`!

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'User': {1: 'User1', 2: 'User1', 3: 'User2', 4: 'User2', 5: 'User2', 6: 'User3', 7: 'User3', 8: 'User4', 9: 'User4', 10: 'User1', 11: 'User1'}, 'Type': {1: 'Game', 2: 'Game', 3: 'Movie', 4: 'Movie', 5: 'Movie', 6: 'Movie', 7: 'Movie', 8: 'Game', 9: 'Movie', 10: 'Movie', 11: 'Movie'}, 'Action': {1: 'Start', 2: 'End', 3: 'Start', 4: 'Start', 5: 'End', 6: 'Start', 7: 'End', 8: 'Start', 9: 'Start', 10: 'Start', 11: 'End'}})
df["Event"] = df.Type + "_" + df.Action.str.lower()  # proxy column
agg = df.groupby(["User", "Event"]).Action.count().unstack().fillna(0)
agg = agg[["Game_start", "Movie_start", "Game_end", "Movie_end"]]
agg.columns.name = ""
```

You're done:

```
>>> print(agg)

       Game_start  Movie_start  Game_end  Movie_end
User                                               
User1         1.0          1.0       1.0        1.0
User2         0.0          2.0       0.0        1.0
User3         0.0          1.0       0.0        1.0
User4         1.0          1.0       0.0        0.0
```

### Iterating on the dataframe

```
from collections import defaultdict
users_count = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda:0))

for row in df.itertuples(): 
    users_count[row.User][f"{row.Type}_{row.Action.lower()}"] += 1

agg = pd.DataFrame(users_count).fillna(0).T
agg = agg[["Game_start", "Movie_start", "Game_end", "Movie_end"]]

print(agg)

       Game_start  Movie_start  Game_end  Movie_end
User1         1.0          1.0       1.0        1.0
User2         0.0          2.0       0.0        1.0
User3         0.0          1.0       0.0        1.0
User4         1.0          1.0       0.0        0.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I reach the same output by iterating trough the dataframe? I am trying to learn how I can apply the answer.

Comment: @Calafalas, I updated and gave a solution using a for loop. See "Iterating on the dataframe".